# Identity involving two related measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question!

The problem at hand is the following:

Let $(X, S, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $X$ be $\sigma$-finite. Let $f: X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be a measurable function, and define a second measure $\nu$ by:

$$\nu(A) = \int\limits_{A} f \ d\mu,$$ for $A \in S.$

Now it is to show that: $$\mu(A) = \int\limits_{A} \frac{1}{f}\ d\nu.$$

We were also given a hint by the professor's assistent to first consider the case $A \subset f^{-1}(a,\lambda * a]$, for positive $a$ and $\lambda > 1$.

Now it is very hard to show my work because I haven't made any significant progress. I first looked at the integral and tried to make some progress using the case where $f$ is a simple function, but I nowhere got a good moment to use the hint and have the feeling that I am stepping in the dark.

As this is part of an exercise, hints are also appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the assistant's hint. Show that
$$\int g \, d\nu = \int fg \, d\mu$$
holds for all nonnegative functions $g$. This follows easily from approximations by simple functions and the monotone convergence theorem.

The original claim follows from applying this identity to $g = \frac{1}{f}$.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring that I am not the only one greatly confused about the hint. I did it just like that by approximating with simple functions and got a proof I am comfortable with now. Thanks!